# revalidatePath() not working when it is deployed on Vercel

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel, http-status-code-304

When I'm Running my code in localhost the revalidation is working fine. But when I hosted my project on Vercel the page is revalidating for a certain time but when I reload or refresh the previously cached data is being displayed again and the network record is also again generating a Status code of 304. Been searching for answers but I couldn't find any.

My repo Link: https://github.com/nikhilbolla/vgse-admin-dashboard

[Here's my Network record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2t7.png)

The Post request is working fine, the data being Added into Database and Displaying for certain amount of time and when I reload the previous cached data is appearing again

I tried updating my vercel config file but unfortunately it couldn't fix any error

```
{
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-store"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm Expecting to fetch the fresh data, on Demand revalidation when I update, Add or Deleting something.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It seems really unreliable for me. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it works for some pages and not others.